# How to build a separate bundle for Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, bundle

I've been looking for a guide or some documentation on building a bundle to be redistributed, and reused. My goal is to have some widget and form definitions that will be common for many projects of mine, and I think, following [some recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10084027/667599), the most symfonian way to write them is within a new separate bundle, which I would like to include in my `deps` file, and install it like I installed the [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) (using composer or including the repos in the deps file).

Could someone please provide a link to a guide to make this or explain me how to do it? I'm aware that Symfony explains the bundle structure in its [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html), but it focuses on bundles for the particular app of the project, not in 3rd party bundles made to be redistributed.