# Separating Common Code In Symfony2 Within my Bundles?

Tags: symfony

I have created Bundles and they share some Common code. (File Upload Class, Gmailer Class) Now I want to create a separate file within my Bundles or Anywhere, where i can put this common code and then I want to create objects of its classes inside all my bundles.

Here is my folder structure

```
-src
  -College
     -StudentBundle
        -Controller
        -Entity
        -OtherApplication
           -All3rdPartyClasseshere.php
     -UserBundle
     -TeacherBundle
```

Now when I tried to auto load it like this

### autoload.php

```
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
'Twig_Extensions_' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig-extensions/lib',
'Twig_'            => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig/lib',
'Uploader_'        => __DIR__.'/../../src/College/StudentBundle/OtherApplications',
```

But when i try to create an object in my controller it gives an error. I didnt use or include anything inside my controller. How could i create objects of the classes that i separated in another file.

Comment: @FractalizeR :- Class not found in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/college/src/College/StudentBundle/Controller/StudentController.php

Answer (score 1):

First of all, third-part libraries, even if they are specifically related to your bundle, should not be inside the bundle structure.

The recommended way to handle your non-bundle common code is to treat it as external libraries, and manage them with [composer.json](http://symfony.com/components).

About the Bundle structure, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-on-symfony-2) can help you get in the right path.