# Where should I place an ImageManager class in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have this MongoDB document: `MyBundle/Document/Image`.

It represents an image, its path, width, and other attributes.

Now I need to manipulate images, and I think that besides my image manipulation library of choice, I should have an app-specific class to deal with this. I think it would be nice to do something like this:

```
$image_manager = new ImageManager;
$image = $image_repository->find($id);
$thumbnail = $image_manager->createThumbnail($image);
```

Now, I'm not sure if I want my ImageManager class to also deal with MongoDB queries, like a custom repository, so let's suppose I don't. Then where should I place my ImageManager class?

Do you think it would be wrong to let it handle both kinds of tasks? (eg: `createThumbnail` and `findAllImagesWithoutThumbnail`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the `Service` folder in my apps at put all the services in there, like:

- `UserService`
- `User\AvatarService`
- `OrganizationService`
- etc...

You could, of course, use `Manager` instead of `Service`, but the idea is the same.

Mostly, my services have methods like:

- `find($id)`
- `save(Class $class)`
- `delete(Class $class)`,
- etc...

Some services have other methods. For example, `User\AvatarService` has the `upload()` method that handles the uploading of the avatar files.

BTW, I [keep my services out of bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-in-symfony-2).

Comment: So your services *call* the repositories, or your services *are* the repositories plus other functionality?

Comment: Theoretically, my services could call repositories, but since just abstracting controllers from the database layer is enough for me right now, I don't have any custom repositories — so, my services are like repositories but with saving and deleting methods that idiomatically don't belong to a repository. If a need arises, I could move the finder methods to custom repositories and call them from services.

Answer (score 0):

I use WideImage in symfony2. I just put it in the vendors and add it to AppKernel.php and autoload. And it's visible project wide.

Comment: Yes I'm using Wideimage too, but I don't know if I should call it from within the Image document.