# SF3: reusable bundle and model updates

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

We currently have several instances of SF3 websites, and we need to create a new bundle that'll be used by some of these instances. To do so, we decided to go with a reusable bundle as discussed [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/best_practices.html) and it seems that everything is working as expected.

The issue we have is regarding entities; how should we create them in the database and, more importantly, how can we update the model when we update the bundle ?

According to a [DoctrineMigration's thread](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/152) this bundle is not to be used the way we want to and the developers do not plan  on adding this feature. [Another bundle](http://docs.campaignchain.com/en/master/package/campaignchain_update.html) seems to do the work but I am unsure on whether it's a good idea or not.

Some documentation states that it is possible to add a mapping in the doctrine configuration node ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816527/symfony2-doctrine2-model-classes-mappings-for-reusable-bundle) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816527/symfony2-doctrine2-model-classes-mappings-for-reusable-bundle)) but I don't think that'll be enough to manage future changes in entities.

Is there any "official" way of doing so ? Did we choose the wrong path and should consider an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

I may be out of bounds, but couldn't you define manually the mappings from the shared bundle?

```
orm:
    auto_mapping: false
    mappings:
        MySharedBundleName:
            type: yml
            dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/MySharedBundleName/Resources/config/doctrine
```

Comment: Yeah sure, I think that'd be the way to go to register the bundle's mapping, but that won't help if any entity has to be upgraded after a change, will it ?