# Best place to define ORM entity for Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, orm

Suppose I have an entity.

This is going to be used in two bundles. But I want bundles to be as indepenent as they could.

Where should I place my entity? In another bundle?

This seems like a good place, since my two main bundles are big enough, and when I want to use them in another project (which happened and happens for me), I have to copy both bundles. Not so good for me.

If I put entity in another light bundle, then I have to move a big bundle and a small bundle. Good, but is there a better way in symfony to do this?

Comment: you should see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-in-symfony-2-x

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. How come I did not find it by googling? Anyway, I would accept your comment as answer if you do it. ThankQ :-)